# Disabling copy of blank text in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

You select a text block or a code using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to copy it to your query window and move your cursor where you want to paste the code.

You accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> again, when you should say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. The copied text block is replaced by an empty block. You have to go back and do the same things again. Is there a solution to this in SQL Server?

Comment: That's how the Clipboard works in Windows (and other OSs). This has nothing to do with SQL Server or programming. When you copy something, it replaces the older clipboard content, even if the new content *seems to be empty*. Windows 10 has [Clipboard History](https://www.howtogeek.com/671222/how-to-enable-and-use-clipboard-history-on-windows-10/) which allows you to select previous content for pasting. Try using `Win+V`

Comment: As explored on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403813/1690217 and in the dupe, this question is actually very much "on-topic" as the IDE has features built into it for this very specific case that questions about _software tools commonly used by programmers_ are on-topic for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL Server or programming. You are right. But luckily I have learned that this behavior can be disabled in SSMS. To do this, I've learned that I need to uncheck Tools> Options> Text Editor> All Languages> General> 'Apply Cut or Copy Commands to blank lines when no selection' checkbox. I tried this and it succeeded. Thank you very much for feedback @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: you should submit that as an answer not a comment - I didn't know about that option

Answer (score 2):

SSMS is a shell of Visual Studio and as such you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to access the [clipboard ring history. This was improved in 2019](https://dailydotnettips.com/view-clipboard-ring-history-in-visual-studio-2019/), but it has been a feature without the UI for a while.

You can also enable [Clipboard History in windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/671222/how-to-enable-and-use-clipboard-history-on-windows-10/), but this feature has saved me a few times in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, I have learned that this behavior can be disabled in SSMS. To do this, I've learned that I need to uncheck menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor* → *All Languages* → *General*. 'Apply Cut or Copy Commands to blank lines when no selection' checkbox. I tried this and it succeeded.